# Intellij IDEA break on exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть такая галочка в настройках, только она работает даже для кода, которого нету у меня в проекте, т.е. может падать где-то в дебрях самой java или tomcat'a.

Можно как-то сделать чтобы прерывалось выполнение только в моём коде/проекте ?

Comment: Так снимите галочку с `Any exception` и добавьте свой фильтр с интересующими классами исключений в `Exception Breakpoints`.

Comment: Так мне как раз нужен любой тип exception'a, но чтобы прерывание было только в моём коде.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос, наверное, стоило бы задать на форуме указанной IDE.

По существу: в настройках точек останова (breakpoints) есть возможность указать Class filters, где можно ввести как отдельный класс, так и маску, а также комбинировать их, перечисляя через запятую. Подробнее [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-breakpoints.html) и [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/breakpoints-2.html).

[image: Breakpoints]